# Оптимизация Java-кода

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Необходимо оптимизировать ниже приведенный кусок кода. В данный момент есть несколько условий, при выполнении которых изменяется видимость TextEdit и ViewText. Всё выполняется нормально, но код выглядит ужасно..

```
private static int countErrors = 0;
    private void makeError()
    {
        countErrors++;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void startSlider_click(View view) {
        countErrors = 0;
        EditText NameTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterNameTextEdit);
        EditText UserFromTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterCityEditText);
        EditText YearsTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterYearsTextEdit);
        TextView NameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enterNameText);
        TextView YearsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enterOldText);
        TextView CityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enterCity);
        CheckBox ruleBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.rulesBox);

        // Создать класс Validator
        // Возможно в аргументы передавать методы
        if (!NameTextEdit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            NameTextEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            NameText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else makeError();

        if(!YearsTextEdit.getText().toString().equals("") && Integer.parseInt(YearsTextEdit.getText().toString())<150) {
            YearsTextEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            YearsText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else makeError();

        if(!UserFromTextEdit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            UserFromTextEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            CityText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else makeError();
        if(ruleBox.isChecked())
        {
            ruleBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else makeError();

        if(countErrors==0){
            DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
            dbHelper.addAccount(NameTextEdit.getText().toString(), UserFromTextEdit.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(YearsTextEdit.getText().toString()));
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatePlan.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: начните с форматирования и разделения отображения и бизнес-логики.

Comment: Имена переменных и полей класса в Java принято писать с маленькой буквы

Comment: @pavloff , хорошо, спасибо, замечание буду принимать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , за бизнес-логику - спасибо, действительно забыл.

Comment: А как обычно лучше всего называть Id объектов, таких как: EditText, TextView. Как я понимаю, нужно называть вещи своими именами и для чего они нужны, но вот заглавными или маленькими буквами? 
Можно какие-то соглашения по коддингу увидеть?

Comment: Есть известный документ - [соглашение о написании Java-кода](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) (Java-convention) где указаны все возможные правила для оформления Java-кода. Дополнительно есть [соглашение Android-разработчика](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html),  которое расширяет конвенцию Java (в android-разработке стоит придерживаться сначала его рекомендаций). В первую очередь стоит обратиться к [разделам именований](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) в этих документах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Заведите метод, который проверяет пустой ли `EditText`, типа:

```
private boolean isEmpty(TextView textView) {
   if(textView==null)
      return true;
   return (textView.getText().toString().length()==0)?true:false;
}
```

2) Парные кОнтролы, типа: `YearsTextEdit` и `YearsText` посадите в один `Layout` и устанавливайте флаг видимости сразу на общий `Layout`

3) Код парсинга строки в целое вынесите в отдельный метод - `parseInt` обладает отвратительным свойством выкидывать `NumberFormatException` - из-за чего вы можете получить неприятный [Überraschung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberraschung) - надо в этом методе его обрабатывать и в случае ошибки выдавать дефолтное значение

4) Перейдите в конце концов на [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) - код намного упростится

5) Почитайте про *Java Naming Convention* - такое ощущение что вы из лагеря шарпистов :)

6) И еще разберитесь со стилями скобок - или вы пишете открывающие скобки на одной строке с кодом или на новой строке - сразу видно, что у вас стиль хромает. Настройте в своем IDE стили форматирования кода.

Comment: На счёт лагеря шарпистов - вы, верно отметили :)